# What do I need to reference to access CustomTextParagraphProperties?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, abstract-class, system.windows.media

Working with TextFormatter, I came accross [this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textformatting.textformatter(v=vs.110).aspx) which shows the following sample code :

```
// Create a TextFormatter object.
TextFormatter formatter = TextFormatter.Create();

// Create common paragraph property settings.
CustomTextParagraphProperties customTextParagraphProperties
    = new CustomTextParagraphProperties();

// Format each line of text from the text store and draw it.
while (textStorePosition < customTextSource.Text.Length)
{
    // Create a textline from the text store using the TextFormatter object.
    using (TextLine myTextLine = formatter.FormatLine(
        customTextSource,
        textStorePosition,
        96 * 6,
        customTextParagraphProperties,
        null))
    {
        // Draw the formatted text into the drawing context.
        myTextLine.Draw(drawingContext, linePosition, InvertAxes.None);

        // Update the index position in the text store.
        textStorePosition += myTextLine.Length;

        // Update the line position coordinate for the displayed line.
        linePosition.Y += myTextLine.Height;
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is even after referencing `System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting` there is no class/object using `CustomTextParagraphProperties` so that line throws an error (of course since it doesn't exist)

What else do I need to reference to access this class ?

This is my `using` list :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting;
using System.IO;
```

And this is the list of my references:

[image: references]

I found `TextParagraphProperties` but this is an `abstract` class and thus can not be created using `new`, meaning it isn't a drop in replacement for `CustomTextParagraphProperties` as the example shows, the following line would not work :

```
TextParagraphProperties tp = new TextParagraphProperties();
```

NOTE: I added the WPF tag as this project inherits WPF functionality, but this is not a WPF project.

I started to delve down a rabbit hole, and finding more and more codependant `abstract` classes the parent depends upon, and since can't use the `new` to inistialize the object, must write a bunch of code, with no end in sight, this is rather frustrating :

```
#region textformatter
    class TextRunProperties : System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextRunProperties {
        public override Windows.Media.Brush BackgroundBrush { get; set; }
        public override Windows.BaselineAlignment BaselineAlignment { get { return base.BaselineAlignment; } }
        public override CultureInfo CultureInfo { get; set; }
        public override double FontHintingEmSize { get; set; }
        public override double FontRenderingEmSize { get; set; }
        public override Windows.Media.Brush ForegroundBrush { get; set; }
        public override Windows.Media.NumberSubstitution NumberSubstitution { get { return base.NumberSubstitution; } }
        public override TextDecorationCollection TextDecorations { get; set; }
        public override Windows.Media.TextEffectCollection TextEffects { get; set; }
        public override Windows.Media.Typeface Typeface { get; set; }
        public override Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextRunTypographyProperties TypographyProperties { get { return base.TypographyProperties; } }
    }

    class TextRun : System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextRun {
        public override CharacterBufferReference CharacterBufferReference { get; set; }
        public override int Length { get; set; }
        public override Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextRunProperties Properties { get; set; }
    }

    class TextSource : System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextSource {
        public override Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextSpan<CultureSpecificCharacterBufferRange> GetPrecedingText( int textSourceCharacterIndexLimit ) {
            return new TextSpan<CultureSpecificCharacterBufferRange>(
                textSourceCharacterIndexLimit,
                new CultureSpecificCharacterBufferRange(
                    new CultureInfo(0),
                    Windows.Media.TextFormatting.CharacterBufferRange.Empty
                )
            );
        }

        public override int GetTextEffectCharacterIndexFromTextSourceCharacterIndex( int textSourceCharacterIndex ) {
            return 0;
        }

        public override Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextRun GetTextRun( int textSourceCharacterIndex ) {
            return new TextRun();
        }
    }

    class TextFormatter : System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextFormatter {
        public override Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextLine FormatLine( Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextSource textSource, int firstCharIndex, double paragraphWidth, TextParagraphProperties paragraphProperties, TextLineBreak previousLineBreak, TextRunCache textRunCache ) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextLine FormatLine( Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextSource textSource, int firstCharIndex, double paragraphWidth, TextParagraphProperties paragraphProperties, TextLineBreak previousLineBreak ) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override Windows.Media.TextFormatting.MinMaxParagraphWidth FormatMinMaxParagraphWidth( Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextSource textSource, int firstCharIndex, TextParagraphProperties paragraphProperties ) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override Windows.Media.TextFormatting.MinMaxParagraphWidth FormatMinMaxParagraphWidth( Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextSource textSource, int firstCharIndex, TextParagraphProperties paragraphProperties, TextRunCache textRunCache ) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }

    class TextLine : System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextLine {
        public override double Baseline {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override int DependentLength {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override double Extent {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
        public override bool HasCollapsed {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
        public override bool HasOverflowed {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override double Height {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override bool IsTruncated {
            get {
                return base.IsTruncated;
            }
        }

        public override int Length {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override double MarkerBaseline {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
        public override double MarkerHeight {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
        public override int NewlineLength {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
        public override double OverhangAfter {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
        public override double OverhangLeading {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
        public override double OverhangTrailing {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
        public override double Start {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
        public override double TextBaseline {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
        public override double TextHeight {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
        public override int TrailingWhitespaceLength {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
        public override double Width {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
        public override double WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        // functions
        public override Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextLine Collapse( params TextCollapsingProperties[] collapsingPropertiesList ) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override void Draw( DrawingContext drawingContext, Windows.Point origin, InvertAxes inversion ) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override CharacterHit GetBackspaceCaretCharacterHit( CharacterHit characterHit ) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override CharacterHit GetCharacterHitFromDistance( double distance ) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override double GetDistanceFromCharacterHit( CharacterHit characterHit ) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override IEnumerable<IndexedGlyphRun> GetIndexedGlyphRuns() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override CharacterHit GetNextCaretCharacterHit( CharacterHit characterHit ) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override CharacterHit GetPreviousCaretCharacterHit( CharacterHit characterHit ) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override IList<TextBounds> GetTextBounds( int firstTextSourceCharacterIndex, int textLength ) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override IList<TextCollapsedRange> GetTextCollapsedRanges() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override TextLineBreak GetTextLineBreak() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override IList<TextSpan<Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextRun>> GetTextRunSpans() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

#endregion
```

I don't even know if that is correct, but from what it seems, none of these `must override` methods return anything, so what exactly does this class do ?  Does it event process any of the code such as getting a TextEffect, or is this all stuff that has to be hand written -- aka, I must make up my own TextEffects and stuff them in that code as whatever abstract structure with more methods that do nothing ....

Answer (score 0):

You will have to derive your own class from `TextParagraphProperties` and override the properties as per your requirement

```
public class CustomTextParagraphProperties  : TextParagraphProperties{...}
```

you will also have to derive `TextRunProperties` and `TextMarkerProperties` to return your own values.

```
public class CustomTextRunProperties : TextRunProperties{...}
public class CustomTextMarkerProperties : TextMarkerProperties{...}
```

Comment: I was just looking into that, and seems to be a rabbit hole with no end in sight. Updating my question to include the implementation I have started, but have no idea.  Am I correct in understanding that `TextRunProperties` and all the various other abstract classes, do nothing -- seems rather silly to require a structure like that but to disallow a 'new' instance of the class to set the one property (eg, text) and have some defaults in place rather than ... well... really LAZY on MS's part XD

Comment: Basically, I want to pass a string to the constructor/class, and then let it do processing for me.  Like when I do, `richTextBox1.Text = "foo"`, the control automatically converts that string to and from RTF format. I don't have to abstract the class and process it all manually writing the entire RTF specification just to set text in a RichTextBox.